# How to force restart StatefulSet programmatically with java client?

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

I modified a file and need to restart a `StatefulSet` to load changed by java client.

I have tried to use `createOrReplaceWithNew`, which can scale down pods but not create new pods and throw `NullPointerException`.

```java
client.apps().statefulSets().inNamespace(currentNamespace).withName(StatefulSet).createOrReplaceWithNew().done();
```

Comment: What is the purpose of restarting StatefulSet? I mean are you sure this is the only way you can achieve your aim?

Comment: By the way, you could get the current definition of a StatefulSet, change some field (eg. an annotation) and apply again.

Comment: @dmkvl I don't think annotations will trigger an update, but labels will.

Comment: @dmkvl Container start-up shell need to read that file to config something, I have to restart pod.